# Cannot connect with slave from Jenkins master. Connection broken

Tags: centos, java, jenkins, continuous-integration

I have setup one Jenkins Master (CentOS 7), and one node on which my project is running (dev environment, Windows 7). My project requirement is Java 1.6.

On my Windows 7 and Java 1.7 machine, I can connect with manage jenkins -> mng node.

When I run the command like:

```
java -jar slave.jar -jnlpUrl http://192.168.100.54:8888/computer/Win7/slave-agent.jnlp
```

Here is the output:

```
Feb 1, 2016 6:45:57 AM hudson.remoting.jnlp.Main createEngine
INFO: Setting up slave: Win7
Feb 1, 2016 6:45:57 AM hudson.remoting.jnlp.Main$CuiListener <init>
INFO: Jenkins agent is running in headless mode.
Feb 1, 2016 6:45:57 AM hudson.remoting.jnlp.Main$CuiListener status
INFO: Locating server among [http://192.168.100.54:8888/]
Feb 1, 2016 6:45:57 AM hudson.remoting.jnlp.Main$CuiListener status
INFO: Handshaking
Feb 1, 2016 6:45:57 AM hudson.remoting.jnlp.Main$CuiListener status
INFO: Connecting to 192.168.100.54:37876
Feb 1, 2016 6:45:57 AM hudson.remoting.jnlp.Main$CuiListener status
INFO: Trying protocol: JNLP2-connect
Feb 1, 2016 6:45:57 AM hudson.remoting.jnlp.Main$CuiListener status
INFO: Connected
Feb 1, 2016 6:45:57 AM hudson.remoting.SynchronousCommandTransport$ReaderThread
run
SEVERE: I/O error in channel channel
java.io.IOException: Unexpected termination of the channel
        at hudson.remoting.SynchronousCommandTransport$ReaderThread.run(SynchronousCommandTransport.java:50)
Caused by: java.io.EOFException
        at java.io.ObjectInputStream$PeekInputStream.readFully(Unknown Source)
        at java.io.ObjectInputStream$BlockDataInputStream.readShort(Unknown Source)
        at java.io.ObjectInputStream.readStreamHeader(Unknown Source)
        at java.io.ObjectInputStream.<init>(Unknown Source)
        at hudson.remoting.ObjectInputStreamEx.<init>(ObjectInputStreamEx.java:48)
        at hudson.remoting.AbstractSynchronousByteArrayCommandTransport.read(AbstractSynchronousByteArrayCommandTransport.java:34)
        at hudson.remoting.SynchronousCommandTransport$ReaderThread.run(SynchronousCommandTransport.java:48)
Feb 1, 2016 6:45:57 AM hudson.remoting.jnlp.Main$CuiListener status
INFO: Terminated
```

If any thing missing, please let me know.

Comment: Did you looked the server logs? They have more detailed info about connection from slaves. JENKINS_HOME/logs/slaves/*/slave.log* You can find more information about slave connection problems on [Jenkins Remoting issue wiki page](https://wiki.jenkins-ci.org/display/JENKINS/Remoting+issue).